# videos does not work on macOS

Tags: mac

After the update on macOS high sierra, videos does not work on all sites. I'm using a tor browser (7.0.6). How to fix it?

Comment: We're going to need more details. Can you provide any more information? All videos? Some videos? Are you running it with default settings?

Comment: @canonizingironize I used tor with default settings on macOS sierra. And everything works fine. After update on macOS high sierra all videos does not work on sites (I use tor with default settings).

Answer (score 0):

Try Refresh Tor Browser option.

1. Goto Options --  [image]
2. Click on [image]
3. Hit "Refresh Tor Browser" Button.

Comment: as far as I know this will infact disable a lot of Tor Browser? at least it has in the past. I'd recommend *not* doing this.